# volume of rotated solid

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating about the $y$-axis the region bounded
by the curves $y = e^{-2x^2}$, $y = 0,$ $x = 0,$ and $x = 1.$

I'm a little confused on what the bounds of the integral would be.

Since it is revolved around the $y$ axis would I use bounds that go on the $y$ axis? If I did I'm thinking that my bounds would be $0$ and $1$ on the $y$ axis?

Or am I wrong and do I use the $x$ axis as my bounds for the integral?

Comment: What is exactly your curve? I am not sure about my rewriting

Comment: @Tong: Perhaps you should have asked first, before changing e^2x2 to $e^2x2$. Neither of them makes any sense, but now it's your fault.

Comment: @TonyK Right this is my fault. For those who are interested in this problem, The original question was y=e^2x2 in the second line before editing.

Comment: Isn't it $y = e^{2x^2}$?

Comment: i apologize its y = e^-2x^2

Comment: how do i use subscript and super?

Comment: @user71317 This site supports the use of MathJax by using a LaTeX-like syntax, see a [quick tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) here.

Comment: @julianfernandez: Negative signs can make a huge difference. Please try to be more cautious in the future.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: Negative signs can make a huge difference. Please try to be more cautious in the future when approving a suggested edit.

Comment: @Amzoti: Negative signs can make a huge difference. Please try to be more cautious in the future when approving a suggested edit.

Comment: @Cameron the OP accepted the answer without the negative sign, that is why I assumed it was his intended equation. Are you sure your edit is the correct one?

Comment: @julian: True. Still, dropping a negative sign in a suggested edit is a bad plan in general, unless you've confirmed things with the OP. New OP's especially are likely to make mistakes of this nature.

Comment: @CameronBuie ok, thanks for the advice!

Comment: @user71317: See my edit to see how to do superscripts. Subscripts work similarly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume it is $y=e^{2x^2}$.  The easiest method is cylindrical shells. That gives
$$\int_0^1 2\pi xe^{2x^2}\, dx,$$
and the integral yields to the substitution $u=2x^2$.

**Remark:** To figure out the bounds, first make a sketch.

Suppose that we will use cylindrical shells. We are rotating about a vertical line, the $y$-axis. Then the "method" consists of taking a thin vertical strip, from $x$ to $x+dx$, and rotating that about the $y$-axis, and then "adding up" (integrating) over all $x$. And we were told $x$ goes from $0$ to $1$. That takes care of the bounds issue.

If we use the method of slicing (cross-sections) then we would need to take cross-sections perpendicular to the $y$-axis. In that case we end up integrating with respect to $y$. For this problem, that method is messier. For one thing, the geometry is different from $y=0$ to $y=1$ than it is later.

**Added:** Since the answer above was posted, the function has changed to $y=e^{-2x^2}$.  Apart from the obvious change in the integrand, nothing much changes. Now it is best to use the substitution $u=-2x^2$.

Comment: FYI: The OP's initial post contained a sign error.

Comment: @CameronBuie: Thank you. I made a minor addition, but kept the original answer.